# magento Remove cart item attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

[image]

how to remove product attribute from conditional  select box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove like this

go to

> app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php

open this file and find this code

```
$attributes['quote_item_price'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Price in cart');
```

just comment this line. attribute will be removed.

**Note:** Please override the core file. Do not change in core file. Clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Override this model function: `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine::getNewChildSelectOptions()`
to this:

```
/**
 * Generate a conditions data
 * @return array
 */
public function getNewChildSelectOptions()
{
    $conditions = parent::getNewChildSelectOptions();
    $conditions = array_merge_recursive(
        $conditions,
        array(
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Conditions Combination'),
                'value' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cart Item Attribute'),
                'value' => $this->_getAttributeConditions(self::PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE_QUOTE_ITEM)
            ),
            // comment here
            /*
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Attribute'),
                'value' => $this->_getAttributeConditions(self::PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE_PRODUCT),
            ),
            */
            array(
                'label' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Product Attribute Assigned'),
                'value' => $this->_getAttributeConditions(self::PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE_ISSET)
            )
        )
    );
    return $conditions;
}
```